# How do I uninstall an old version of Mathematica?

Tags: windows, installation

My SSD is getting full, and while trying to clean it up, I found one of the largest things on here is an installation of Mathematica 10.3. As this is an outdated version, I would like to remove it, but I can't seem to figure out how to cleanly do that. Mathematica 10.3 doesn't show up in the Windows Programs and Features prompt (though 10.4 does, which is the version I want to keep on here), but it's still present on the disk.

This is on Windows 8.1, incidentally.

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this. But I couldn't find anything from an internet search or on Wolfram's website, so this is the best place I could think of to ask.

Comment: I believe it should be safe to simply remove the installation directory. The configuration is shared with other versions, so it should not be removed.

Comment: You may use Cleaner or UninstallTool to this end. Verified  myself.